# Dequeue function not outputting proper values

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, queue

There seems to be an issue with my `dequeue` function within a queue class that I have. My `dequeue` function which is part of the position class, is not returning the correct values that have been enqueued into the list.

The values that have been enqueued are which is a position object, are 2,1 and -1, but when I dequeue that object i get 2,506216, and -1; When I assign the `*pos` ponter to an object I am left with the default values;The enqueue function seems to be working correctly for when I check the `ptr` values they are correct.

```
//position constructor
front = back = &header;

        struct Posnode
        {   
           Position *pos;
           Posnode *next;    
        };
    class Position
    private:
              Posnode *front,*back,header;
void Position::dequeue(Position&p)
{
    Posnode *ptr=front->next;
    front->next = ptr->next;
    p = *ptr->pos;
    p.geta();//checking for values but am left with the default

    if (back == ptr)
    {
        back = front;
    }
    delete ptr;

}
v

oid Position::enqueue(Position n) //assigning Position object to end of queue
    {
        Posnode *ptr = new Posnode;
        ptr-> pos =  &n;
        back->next = ptr;
        back = ptr;

        return;
    }
```

Position copy,intial(5);
        copy = intial;

```
        if (copy.ismovelegal(posmoves, r))
        {
            copy.makemove(posmoves, r);


            if (intial.solved(copy))
            {
                cin.get();
            }
            else
            {
                p.enqueue(copy);


            }
        }
        copy.free();//clearing object private memebers
    }
    intial.free();

    p.dequeue(o);//copy that was previous enqued is not enqued
    o.geta();
```

Comment: Is this homework? If yes, use the homework tag

Comment: It would be easier to find the error if you could post a minimal, working program that still exhibits the problem. The code you have posted doesn't compile, and it is possible that the error is in the parts you have removed.

Comment: Would you edit your post so that your code sample is something that actually compiles?

Comment: Don't you delete the *second* element of the queue? Or does `*front` have special semantics in your implementation? With your code fragment, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: in the default constructor i have 'front = back = &header;'

Comment: What type of objects are being stored in this dequeue? Can you show the copy constructor/assignment operator for the object's class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Check out the Implementation of Deque first and then try your own. If its some syntax or semantic error post minimal code that reproduces your code.

this link might help you. [Deque Implementation](http://login2win.blogspot.in/2011/06/c-deque.html)